# How to handle parallel PUT/PATCH requests in Django Rest Framework? (Overwrite issue)

Tags: django, python-3.x, parallel-processing, django-rest-framework, api-design

I'm developing a Web App for a uni project and it's about airports and carriers...

## Problem

The problem is when I try to feed to the database I'm doing in a parallel way because in the json file I'm using as the reference there is a lot of entries about carriers and airports.

When you update(PUT and PATCH) one by one in a sequential way it is working as it should but when I try PUT/PATCH parallel requests the instance in the DB is being overwritten every time.

**Each airport has a list of carriers and when I tried to add more carriers to that list via PUT or PATCH in a parallel way it overwrites the instance previous carriers list**

My models are:

```
class Carrier(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
    name = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Airport(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
    name = models.TextField()
    carriers = models.ManyToManyField(Carrier, related_name='airports')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Serializers:

```
class AirportListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='airport-detail')

    class Meta:
        model = models.Airport
        fields = ('code', 'name', 'url')

class AirportDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='airport-detail')

    class Meta:
        model = models.Airport
        fields = ('code', 'name', 'url', 'carriers')
```

And I'm having problems with my update method I had to override it because for appending new data to the carriers array of an instance of an airport:

```
def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()

        serializer = serializers.AirportDetailSerializer(
            instance=instance,
            data=request.data,
            context={'request': request}
        )

        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            # Getting the user inputed carriers after it was validated by the serializer
            carriers = set(dict(request.data)['carriers'])    
            # Adding new carriers to the current airport list of carriers without deleting the old ones
            for carrier in serializer.validated_data['carriers']:
                print(carrier)
                carriers.add(carrier)
            print('Carriers %s' % carriers)
            # Saving alterations to the db
            serializer.save(carriers=carriers)

        # Overriding the original data for more features
        data = serializer.data
        # Creating the carrier links 
        data['carriers'] = ['http://%s/api/carriers/%s/' % (request.get_host(), carrier) for carrier in data['carriers']]

        return Response(data)
```

Example of entry in DRF Browsable API: 
[image]

Comment: Does the `print(carrier)` in the loop print the original carriers like you thought it would?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you are calling `serializer.save(carriers=carriers)`, you are saving the `Airport` instance with only the carriers from your particular PUT/PATCH request...rather than adding carriers to your `Airport` instance.

You should look at the docs for [writable nested serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers) and use a separate `CarrierSerializer`.

On a related note, your `update` logic is better suited as part of the `AirportSerializer`, not your view. This makes it more reusable. That section of the DRF docs is the perfect example for you.

Something like this pseudo-code adapted from the Albums/Tracks example:

```
class AirportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    carriers = CarrierSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Airport
        fields = ......

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        carriers_data = validated_data.pop('carriers')
        for carrier in carriers_data:
            Carrier.objects.update_or_create(airport=instance, defaults=carrier_data)
        return instance
```